# lex: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Tags: api, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I am trying send request to lex using postman through I enter the correct access keyId and Secret Key , I am getting response as below:

```
<InvalidSignatureException>

<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature 
you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.
Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>

</InvalidSignatureException>
```

Postman request:

[image]